# Update issue with mandb and makewhatis

Tags: linux, man

When I change a given manpage, `apropos` and `whatis` do only reflect these changes when I perform the following steps:

1. store a copy of the manpage elsewhere and delete it in `/usr/local/man/man1`
2. run `makedb`
3. run `makewhatis`
4. restore the manpage in `/usr/local/man/man1`
5. run `makedb`
6. run `makewhatis`

Details:

When I change the NAME section to contain a certain keyword which should be found by `apropos`, it will only be found by `apropos` after performing the six (!) steps described above.

It is definitely not sufficient, just to update with `mandb` and `makewhatis`. I know that I can recreate the `whatis` database by `makewhatis -c`, but an update process which requires the deletion of the database first, is somewhat weird.

Question:

How can I change a manpage and have this change reflected by `apropos` and `whatis` without the deletion/restore/update process?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I change a manpage and have this change reflected by `apropos` and `whatis`?

You should be using [mandb](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mandb/) - create or update the manual page index caches.

> `mandb` is used to initialise or manually update index database caches. The caches contain information relevant to the current state of the manual page system and the information stored within them is used by the `man-db` utilities to enhance their speed and functionality.

`mandb` will update the databases uses by both `apropos` and `whatis`.

Source: [mandb: create or update the manual page index caches - Linux Man Pages (8)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mandb/)

> The database searched by `apropos` is updated by the `mandb` program.
> Depending on your installation, this may be run by a periodic
> cron job, or may need to be run manually after new manual pages
> have been installed.

Source [apropos(1) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html)

> Each manual page has a short description available within it.
> `whatis` searches the manual page names and displays the manual
> page descriptions of any name matched.

> index databases are used during the search, and are updated by
> the `mandb` program.  Depending on your installation, this may be
> run by a periodic cron job, or may need to be run manually after
> new manual pages have been installed.

Source: [whatis(1) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whatis.1.html)

Comment: The process you explain in your answer is exactly what doesn't work for me. That's the reason for my question. I'm sorry if this wasn't explained clearly enough by me.

Comment: @N.A.McBee What options did you give `mandb` and what was the exit status?

Comment: @N.A.McBee did you try `mandb -c`? "This option forces mandb to delete previous databases and re-create them from scratch"

Comment: I used `mandb` without options and tried out `makewhatis -c`. I still wonder why I should have to rebuild the whole database instead of just updating it with respect to a single new file version.

Comment: The exit status of `sudo mandb` seems always to be `0`.